# What I need to know when using shared database connection?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, heroku, sinatra

I'm developing FB app on Heroku, using Ruby, Sinatra and Mongo. I think that sharing database connection is a good idea but I don't know how it looks on production.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to [connection pooling](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/#Connection_Pooling)?

Comment: Right, connection pooling. How many parallel connections to database can handle one instance, when I need increase number of instances representing database connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you have looked or researched.

In addition to @Stennie's link above, check out the following links -

- Look at the actual source code of the ruby driver on [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/). There's ample information there, including a section and an example of connection pooling.
- Check out the overall [ruby driver information](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center)
- Some [notes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Notes+on+Pooling+for+Mongo+Drivers) on pooling within the drivers.
- See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327416/mongodb-what-is-connection-pooling-and-timeout) answered by the original Ruby driver author on So.

If you're not using connection pooling, you may see the following [messages](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/?highlight=connection%20pooling#why-does-mongodb-log-so-many-connection-accepted-events) in your logs.