# Large Data import from MySQL to MongoDB with mongify fails

Tags: mysql, ruby, mongodb

I try to import large data from mysql to mongodb. Everything is right, till I get this error:

```
`checkout': could not obtain connection within 5.0 seconds. The max pool size is currently    1; consider increasing the pool size or timeout. (Mongo::ConnectionTimeoutError)
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @apesa MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9 and MySQL Server version: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 (Ubuntu)

Comment: This looks like a possible Rails issue in that the connection pool for the Ruby driver defaults to 1. You can also refer to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327416/mongodb-what-is-connection-pooling-and-timeout/2327888#2327888

Comment: @apesa Does that mean that there is no solution for my problem?

Comment: Are you using Passenger with Rails? It looks like the solution lies in the Rails Driver config

Comment: @apesa Sorry, I#m absolut beginner with Ruby. I only want use Monfigy... :(

Comment: How do you have Mongify connecting to MySQL? Passenger?? If so you need to try and disable Connection Pooling since you probably don't need it. I am commenting because I am not exactly sure, but I would look at how my Driver is connecting to MySQL.